# RNA definition type in user preference > input , how can I change this?

Tags: interface

[image]

Hi. I want to add a new hotkey in Blender. 
So, 'User Preferences > Input > + Add New' give me a hotkey slot and I name it as 'rotate view' with 'Alt + LMB' key.

However, I can't change the RNA. I guess it's about function of this hotkey.
How can I get this work?

Comment: Mouse
Available as mouse events are mouse movements, mouse wheel rolls, and any of the mouse buttons, on press, release or either. Aliases for the overall 'Select With: LMB/RMB' preference are available as the 'Select Mouse' or 'Action Mouse' button click events.
Modifier keys
The above events can be combined with the standard Ctrl/Alt/OS/Cmd modifiers in order to change their function As well as these, any other key can be used as a modifier key, for example the Grease Pencil tool is mapped to mouse tweak, with 'D' as the modifier key so the tool is used by holding 'D' and dragging the mouse

Comment: Check : http://archive.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-256-beta/custom-keyboard-shortcuts/index.html

Comment: ChecK : http://download.blender.org/documentation/BlenderHotkeyReference.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RNA value comes from the operator named above. Were you have entered "rotate view" needs to be the name of the operator to be run when the key/mouse combination is pressed. The standard operator to rotate the view would be `view3d.rotate`.

To get the value of a custom operator, you need to use the value of `bl_idname` defined in the operator you wish to use.

Some operators will have other properties that can be set as well -

[image]

This appears a little misleading as the options appear disabled, when in fact that shows they are default values, changing the values highlights them and shows an 'X' to return to default values.